# "Critical" vulnerability rating on OpenVAS 9

Tags: linux, vulnerabilities, openvas

I'm using OpenVAS 9 and I noticed that all the vulnerabilities ranking from 7.0 to 10.0 are labeled as "High".

Is there a way to change this behavior, so that all the ones ranking from 9.0 to 10.0 can be labeled as "Critical" (as specified by CVSSv3)?

Many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are currently only the following four different severity ratings available within the settings (top right of the GSA Web GUI) of your user:

```
Here the classification of the vulnerability respective to the score can be defined.

    NVD Vulnerability Severity Ratings
        7.0 - 10.0: High
        4.0 - 6.9: Medium
        0.0 - 3.9: Low
    BSI Vulnerability Traffic Light
        7.0 - 10.0: Red
        4.0 - 6.9: Yellow
        0.0 - 3.9: Green
    OpenVAS classic
        5.1 - 10.0: High
        2.1 - 5.0: Medium
        0.0 - 2.0: Low
    PCI-DSS
        4.3 - 10.0: High
        0.0 - 4.2: None
```

http://docs.greenbone.net/GSM-Manual/gos-4/en/gui_introduction.html#my-settings

Disclaimer: NVT Dev @ Greenbone